# Can hyperledger and ethereum can be connected for transferring data or asset between each other?

Tags: integration, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum, data-transfer

Can hyperledger and ethereum be connected for transferring data asset between each other?

“simple” EVM smart contracts can now be deployed to Hyperledger Sawtooth using the “Seth” (Sawtooth Ethereum) Transaction Family.

Is any plugin or application available to communicate between two different blockchain platforms?

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger is a consortium that includes multiple blockchain platforms, including Hyperledger Burrow (A EVM), Hyperledger Sawtotoh (with Seth, that uses Burrow), and Hyperledger Fabric (which also recently includes a EVM).

The Hyperledger blockchain technologies are, in general, private or permissioned blockchain platforms. While Ethereum is a public blockchain platform (except for Enterprise Ethereum).

Basically, one will need to write a connector to communicate between the two blockchains (if you want to connect to the public Ethereum blockchain). Otherwise, you can base everything on Sawtooth's Seth or Fabric's EVM equivalent.